# inplace edit question

Tags: jquery, inplace-editing

i have a very nice inplace edit

mootools inlineEdit Plugin and you can test it on this link

http://dev.justinmaier.com/inlineEdit2/

but there is proplem in use it in my project becouse i use jquery and i try

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

but didn't  work because the code is too complex 
i like the mootools because it make text with all style not need input box or update just one click to edit and edit when the text still have style :)

so it is possible to have same effect use jquery ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `jQuery.noConflict`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)]</sup>* you need to use `jQuery` to create your jQuery objects, not `$`. Then, MooTools and jQuery will play nice together.

Comment: thank you but the code to complex it i use javascript with jquery i try as u say to and try the three way of use jQuery.noConflict but it still did'nt work so i need realy some thing like mootools inlineEdit Plugin in jquery

Comment: No, really. If you call `noConflict` you have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`, because the jQuery library doesn't use `$` for anything then.